# Does the family obtained by removing nowhere dense sets from open sets form a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the standard topology on the real line, and let $\mathcal{N}$ be the ideal of all nowhere dense sets. Denote $\mathcal{S}=\{U\setminus N\colon\  U\in\mathcal{T},\,N\in\mathcal{N}\}$.

**Question:** Is $\mathcal{S}$ a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Clearly $\mathcal{S}$ contains $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$. It is also easy to see that $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under finite intersections and finite unions, since $(U\setminus M)\cap(V\setminus N)=(U\cap V)\setminus(M\cup N)$ and $(U\setminus M)\cup(V\setminus N)\supseteq(U\cup V)\setminus(M\cup N)$. But I am not able to find out whether it is closed under arbitrary unions.

Comment: Is it an ideal in the algebraic sense? what is the ring? the power set ring with symmetric difference  as addition and intersection as multiplication?

Comment: This is similar to the topology induced by Lesbegue measurable sets, have you compared and contrasted these?

Comment: @stressed-out: A set-theoretic ideal, that is, a family of sets closed under taking subsets and finite unions.

Comment: @stressed-out As already pointed out, there is the concept of set theoretic ideals. However, they are in fact ideals in the algebraic sense. In this case over the ring $(\mathcal P(\mathbb R), \Delta, \cap, ^c, \emptyset, \mathbb R)$, where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference (and addition in this ring), $\cap$ is the intersection (and multiplication in this ring), $^c$ is complementation (and maps elements to their inverse in this ring), $\emptyset$ is the additive neutral, and $\mathbb R$ is the multiplicative neutral element. That, however, doesn't really help with the question.

Comment: @Eddy: I have found a paper  _Topologies which generate a complete measure algebra_ by S. Scheinberg where it is claimed that the family of all standard open sets minus a set of measure zero forms a topology. However, the argument used there (before Theorem 2.1) is not clear to me. Is this what you have on mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\mathcal S$ is closed under arbitrary unions.

Suppose $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\setminus N_i)$ where each $U_i$ is open and each $N_i$ is nowhere dense (meaning "open" and "nowhere dense" in the standard topology of $\mathbb R$). I have to show that $A=U\setminus N$ for some open set $U$ and some nowhere dense set $N.$

Let $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i.$ Since $A\subseteq U,$ we have $A=U\setminus N$ where $N=U\setminus A.$ Clearly $U$ is open. I have to show that $N$ is nowhere dense; in other words, I have to show that, for every nonempty open set $V,$ there is a nonempty open set $W\subseteq V$ such that $W\cap N=\emptyset.$

Let $V$ be a nonempty open set. If $V\cap U=\emptyset,$ we can just take $W=V.$ Suppose $V\cap U\ne\emptyset.$ Then $V\cap U_i\ne\emptyset$ for some $i\in I.$ Since $N_i$ is nowhere dense, there is a nonempty open set $W\subseteq V\cap U_i$ such that $W\cap N_i=\emptyset.$ Then $W\subseteq U_i\setminus N_i\subseteq A,$ so $W\cap N=\emptyset.$

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem. And it is really a nice proof! I wonder, is there any standard name for this topology?

Comment: @PeterElias I don't know if this topology has a name.